# Android network listener

Tags: android, networking, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Please help solve the problem.
Task: create a Network Listener. When the Internet is lost, show ProgressDialog.

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
private IntentFilter mNetworkStateChangedFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkStateIntentReceiver;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mNetworkStateChangedFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mNetworkStateChangedFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);

        mNetworkStateIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



            if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                mTypeName = info.getTypeName();
                mSubtypeName = info.getSubtypeName();
                mAvailable = info.isAvailable();

                Log.i(LOGTAG, "Network Type: " + mTypeName 
                    + ", subtype: " + mSubtypeName
                    + ", available: " + mAvailable + " isConnected: " + info.isConnected());
                if (!info.isConnected()){
                    try{
                    showDialog();
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }

                    }
                else if (info.isConnected()){
                        dismissDialog();    
                }

            }
            }
        };

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Check the emulator. I go into the settings (operation OnPause), unplug the internet, I go back (onResume) - to create a dialogue, it's okay. Again in settings, turn on the Internet, the dialogue remains.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver);
    };
    @Override
    protected void onResume() { 
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver, mNetworkStateChangedFilter);
        unregisterReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver);
        registerReceiver(mNetworkStateIntentReceiver, mNetworkStateChangedFilter);
    };



public void showDialog() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "");
    }

public void dismissDialog() {
    try {
        dialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, e.getMessage()); //Crash application
    }

    }
```

Unsuccessful attempt to debug. `Log.i(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());` in dismissDialog() leads to crash application.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x10000000 (has extras) } in com.t.network.MainActivity$1@40519848

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

How i can listen connection with using Progress/Allert dialogs?

Thank

P.S.

```
Log.i(LOGTAG, "Network Type: " + mTypeName 
                    + ", subtype: " + mSubtypeName
                    + ", available: " + mAvailable + " isConnected: " + info.isConnected());
```

work normal

P.P.S. I apologize for my English :)

Comment: "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message" -> try using e.printStackTrace() instead of e.getMessage()

Comment: you have try as `String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"ERROR TEST ERROR":e.getMessage();
Log.e(LOGTAG,err); `   ??

Comment: Dialog not dismissing. `public void showDialog() {
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  dialog.setMessage("message");
  dialog.setCancelable(false);
  dialog.show();
 }

 public void dismissDialog() {
  try {
   if (dialog !=null) {dialog.dismiss(); dialog = null;}
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }` - no errors. But dialog turn on...

Comment: Problem solved. 

   `public void dismissDialog() {
      try {
       if (dialog !=null) {
         dialog.dismiss();
         dialog = null;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    
     }`

and call dismissDialog() in showDialog(), onPause() and onResume() method's. 
Thanks for all